# How to drop min and max for each line. Java

Tags: java

```
public class Average {

static Integer[][] myDouble = new Integer[10][12];
static int x = 0, y = 0;
static int strDouble;

public Average() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StudentIdAverage.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\\s+");

            for (String str : values) {
                strDouble = Integer.parseInt(str);
                myDouble[x][y] = strDouble;
                y = y + 1;
            }
            x = x + 1;
            y = 0;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Average arr = new Average();

    for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) {
        IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.asList(myDouble[i]).stream().filter(intValue -> intValue != null).collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
        System.out.println("Average: " + statistics.getAverage() + ", min: " + statistics.getMin() + ", max: " + statistics.getMax());
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < myDouble.length; ++k) {
        int count = 0; // count the values used to calculate sum
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < myDouble[k].length; ++j) {

            if (myDouble[k][j] == null) //skip the null values
            {

                continue;
            }

            //Arrays.sort(myDouble[i]);
            sum += myDouble[k][j];
            count++;
            System.out.print(Average.myDouble[k][j] + " ");

        }
        average = (sum / count); //use count instead of lenght

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(average);

    }
}
```

}

input txt file

> 45 72 90 50 67 63 81 71 55 56 80 74/n 55 54 79 72 75 68/n 51 88 79 72/n 98 52 52 53 50 92 67 99 92 50 61 91/n 94 48 53 92 97/n 97 69 77 74 68 54 87 74 54 83 58 69/n 75 49 87 61 66 53 79 48 96 60/n 58 71 51 73 53 75 93 81 45 69 78 65/n 50 88 78 81 99 61 97 70 87 80 69/n 91 89 97 80 93 82 92 49 52 69 96 61

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with this ? See what is a [mcve] please.

Comment: the code is good , I am just having trouble to drop min and max for each line .

Comment: **What do you mean by "_drop min and max_", and what is the trouble ? I can't read you mind so you need to explain your problem.**
FYI : `average = (sum / count);` won't be correct because `int / int` gives a `int`. (and you even declare `average` like one) but it is unlikely to be an integer. use `double average = 1.0 * sum / count;` or an equivalent.

Comment: agree , I will fix it

Comment: every line has min and max. I have to find it for each line then delete and calculate the average with the new numbers

Comment: What if you have twice the min or max value ? You need to remove both or only one ? Keep the current logic (the sum), in that loop, you need to also keep a trace of the min/max to at the end substract those values (which is a bit more complicate if those value can be find more than once)

Comment: It should drop the highest and the lowest number for each line. For simplicity just once.

Comment: Next time, please include everything in the question, it will be much easier and will prevent those downvote you had. It is still time to [edit] the question to include those information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an array, `myDouble[k]` of size `myDouble[k].length` (call it L), *dropping the min and max* really means **ignore** the min and max. Since the sum is calculated as average/size, ignore the min and max values.

The sum is in the form `newsum + min + max`. Obtain the new sum by subtracting min and max from sum: `sum -= (min + max)`.

You can get the `min` and `max` manually so you really are using just one for loop. Start min and max at the first non-null entry, and update min and max if the next entry is strictly less or strictly greater than the (candidate) current value, respectively.

The new size will also decrease by two (Beware if size is two or less!). That means, the average excluding min and max is the new `sum/(myDouble[k].length - 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep track of the min and max value then substract both value at the end. You don't need to change the rest. This will allow you to get the average value without the need to read the line twice (to remove those values).

```
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int j = 0; j < myDouble[k].length; ++j) {

        if (myDouble[k][j] == null) // skip the null values
        {
            continue;
        }

        min = Math.min(myDouble[k][j], min);
        max = Math.max(myDouble[k][j], max);

        ...
    }
    sum = sum - min - max;
```

If you can find those value twice, you will need to use a way to count the occurrence of those value. But you get the idea here.

---

Note that another solution would be to sort the array then skip the first and last value :

```
double[] sortedArray = Arrays.sort(myDouble[k]);
for (int j = 1; j < sortedArray.length - 1; ++j) {
    sum += sortedArray[j];
}
```

This solution is easier but required more memory, for big list I would not recommend it (but performance is not an issue)